# Can I do the same WPF client + MVC and web.api 2.0 better/easier?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, wpf, asp.net-web-api2, webclient

I need to implement following: WPF client uploads image via web.api. As soon as image gets uploaded, it must automatically appear on the page in browser.

My solution is:
WPF calls following web-api method:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        var imgFileAsByteArr = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        _lastUploadedSrc = 
            $"Images/{Request.Headers.First(h => h.Key == "fileName").Value.First()}";

        File.WriteAllBytes(
            HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + _lastUploadedSrc), 
            imgFileAsByteArr);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Before returnin 200 OK code I save image file name to the _lastLoadedSrc.

Each 2 seconds following script asks another web-api method if there is something new that needs to be displayed:
`<script>
    // ATTENTION:
    // ajax below would create wrong URL if triggered from .../Home/Index startpoint!
    setInterval(function () {
        var hasUpdate = $.ajax("api/image/HasUpdate").done(
            function (data) {
                if (data === true) {
                    var lastUploadedSrc = $.ajax("api/image/LastUploadedSrc").done(
                        function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#img-container').append(
                                "<img src='" + data + "' />");
                        });
                }
            });
    }, 2000);
</script>`

If update is present, it calls another web-api method, which return img src from the property above and makes sure that there nothing to update any more.

**MY QUESTION IS SIMPLE: I have strong feeling that this solution is comlicated and out of 'good practicies'. I am doing such kind of stuff FIRST TIME. Can someone suggest me a better way to achieve the same goal?**

Comment: Your most obvious problem, if I'm reading this right (you don't show exactly what `api/image/HasUpdate` and `api/image/LastUploadedSrc` does), is that if another image is uploaded before your refresh script runs, then you will miss the first image.

Comment: @Mutt Burland that's OK. I have more serious doubts about the solution itself. Maybe I don't need so much web api methods? Maybe I can simplify something somehow?

Comment: You could just return the address from your `Post` method to start with.

Comment: @MattBurland No, I cant. According to my task, this method MUST return status code. Means 200 OK or BadRequest.

Comment: A status code and the message content are two different things.

Comment: @MattBurland O! I didn't know that. How should i rewrite code in your way?

Comment: @MattBurland I just don't understand. If I return the  adress directly from Post, what should my ajax do? It gonna call Post, right? Byt Post expects byte array to be given to him? Post is serving for one purpose only: take image and save it.

Comment: I don't think your approach is gonna work. First thing I notice is that you save the path to _lastUploadedSrc and I assume you try to read it from there in the other api. Web Api is stateless, in rest services each request is independent from another. _lastUploadedSrc variable will be recreated for every new request.

Comment: @Arnel no, you wrong. since it is static, it is shared between all the requests. I tested this code: it works perfectly.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know it was static. Another approach could be to use the same name for the last image and every time the wpf app upload a new image set the same name and change the name of the old image or remove it, then use your js to refres the img. Not sure if this can work for you...